# Laravel project on production : Routes ain't working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I pushed my laravel 5 project online, on production. Everything was working fine on localhost, but now, online, the routes are not working anymore.

The index, is working but when I want to go to an other page of the project, it's returning an internal server error...

Does someone know where this issue could come from ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a linux hosting environment?

Comment: If so then is it nginx or apache?

Comment: I don't know, it's a simple hosting. However, in local I'm under linux apache

Comment: Try checking if the "rewriting" is enabled or not... Laravel uses URL rewriting .. and also the basic folder permission stuff

Comment: if you are on shared hosting, make document_root to /public

Comment: Where shall I check that ? on the hosting online or in my code ?

Comment: You have to tell your hosting provider to do that...

Comment: Ok So I have to call them is it ?

Comment: Depends what kind of hosting provider you have chosen as well .

Comment: If you can access via the terminal then great you wont have to call them

Comment: Go to /public/index.php and on 2nd line add phpinfo(); dd(); and search for DOCUMENT_ROOT you will know what you stand on.

Comment: But by default php errors displaying are disabled

Comment: Try that in index file : -- <?php 
 ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

Comment: I can access in SSH would it help ? Ok I'll do that and tell you what it returns thanks

Comment: If you can ssh just check if the apache/nginx service has mod rewrite enabled .. You may have to google for that

Comment: It can actually only enabled as I have other projects in this same server which are using mod rewrite as well

Comment: Folder permissions?

Comment: Folder permissions are 072